# Updating an input's bound value when edited

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm working on a basic to-do application. Each to-do/task item gets listed as an input item in a Vue `<list-item>` component, and the `<list-item>`s are displayed with a v-for pointing to a tasks array.

I'm trying to allow the user to edit each task input, and upon changing the value, have this update the array item (rather than just the input itself). My @change event on the input is firing, but I'm at a loss as to what to do after this point.

https://jsfiddle.net/xbxm7hph/

HTML:

```
<div class="app">

    <div class="add-control-area columns is-mobile is-multiline">

        <responsive-container>

            <div class="field is-grouped">
                <div class="control is-expanded">
                    <input class="input add-control-text" type="text" placeholder="New Task" v-model="newTask" v-on:keyup.enter="addTask">
                </div>
                <div class="control">
                    <a class="button is-white add-control-button" @click="addTask" :disabled="!isThereText">Add Task</a>
                </div>
            </div>

        </responsive-container>

        <responsive-container>

            <list-item v-for="task, index in tasks" :item="task" :index="index" @task-completed="completeTask(index)" @task-deleted="deleteTask(index)" ></list-item>

        </responsive-container>

    </div>

</div>
```

JS:

```
Vue.component('list-item', {
    props: ['item', 'index'],
    template: `<div class="task-wrapper">

<input class="task" :value="item" @change="updateTask()">

    <div class="task-control delete-task" @click="deleteTask()"></div>
    <div class="task-control complete-task" @click="completeTask()"></div>

</div>
  `,
  methods: {
    completeTask: function() {
      this.$emit('task-completed', this.index);
    },
    deleteTask: function() {
      this.$emit('task-deleted', this.index);
    },
    updateTask: function() {
      console.log('changed');
    }
  }
});

Vue.component('responsive-container', {
  template: `
    <div class="column is-4-desktop  is-offset-4-desktop is-10-tablet is-offset-1-tablet is-10-mobile is-offset-1-mobile">
            <div class="columns is-mobile">
                <div class="column is-12">
                  <slot></slot>
                </div>
            </div>
  </div>
  `
});

var app = new Vue({
    el: '.app',
  data: {
        tasks: [],
    completedTasks: [],
    newTask: ''
  }, 
  methods: {
    addTask: function() {
      if(this.isThereText) {
        this.tasks.push(this.newTask);
        this.newTask = '';
        this.updateStorage();
      }
    },
    completeTask: function(index) {
      this.completedTasks.push(this.tasks[index]);
      this.tasks.splice(index, 1);
      this.updateStorage();
    },
    deleteTask: function(index) {
      this.tasks.splice(index, 1);
      this.updateStorage();
    },
    updateStorage: function() {
      localStorage.setItem("tasks", JSON.stringify(this.tasks));
    }
  },
  computed: {
    isThereText: function() {
      return this.newTask.trim().length;
    }
  },

  // If there's already tasks stored in localStorage,
  // populate the tasks array
  mounted: function() {
    if (localStorage.getItem("tasks")) {
      this.tasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tasks"));    
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`v-model` directive](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Form-Input-Components-using-Custom-Events) on your `<list-item>` component, instead of passing in an `item` property. You will also need to pass in a reference from the array (`tasks[index]`), because `task` in this scope is a copy that is not bound to the element of the array:

```
<list-item v-for="task, index in tasks" v-model="tasks[index]"></list-item>
```

In your component definition for the list item, you'll need to now take in a `value` prop (this is what gets passed when using `v-model`) and set a data property `item` to that value. Then, emit an `input` event on the change to pass the `item` value (this is what the component is listening for when using `v-model`):

```
Vue.component('list-item', {
  props: ['value'],
  template: `<div class="task-wrapper">
    <input class="task" v-model="item" @change="updateTask"></div>
  </div>
  `,
  data() {
    return {
      item: this.value,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    updateTask: function() {
      this.$emit('input', this.item);
    }
  }
});
```

[Here's a fiddle with those changes.](https://jsfiddle.net/xbxm7hph/1/)

---

- As Bert Evans mentioned, even though this works, Vue requires that components using the `v-for` directive also use a `key` attribute (you will get a warning from Vue otherwise):

  ```
   <list-item
     v-for="task, index in tasks" 
     :key="index"
     v-model="tasks[index]"
   ></list-item>
  ```
- Also, realize that the `index` variable in a `v-for` scope can change, meaning that the item at index 1 might change to index 4 and this can pose some problems as the application gets more complex. A better way would be to store `items` as an object with an `id` property. This way you can have an immutable id associated with the item.

Comment: `key` is required for custom components. The parentheses on the method handlers are superfluous. Also you're binding directly to `value` which is modifying a property. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Components-and-v-for

Comment: @BertEvans why not use `index`? And I know the documentation says `key` is required, but isn't that just if you want the data to bind? I think `v-model` circumvents that. I get the expected results and no errors or warning in the fiddle.

Comment: You don't get warnings because he is using the production verison of Vue. We keep getting questions from people using `index` as a variable to their components. The problem is `index` changes and `id`s do not.

Comment: @BertEvans Ok good call. I'll update my answer to include a PSA

Comment: @BertEvans, wait your first comment changed?

Comment: Yeah, I backed off the `index`. It may be more personal preference. We *do* see a number of questions where people are using `index` then mutating the list and running into trouble, so I personally lean away from it. You probably saw an early version of the comment before I edited. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the index and new value to your change event handler:

```
<input class="task" :value="item" @change="updateTask(index, $event)">
```

Then access them accordingly:

```
updateTask: function(index, event) {
    console.log(index);          
    console.log(event.target.value);  
}
```